# Connecting a Javascript client with Node.js/express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My friend finished developing a functioning client website via Javascript. I have my server code running in which it grabs certain data via MySQL. Could you guys give us some tips on how we could connect the Node.js server code to the client side? (in which we're hoping for the client side and server side to be separate, and have a medium connecting both together). From what I've gathered from my research, socket could be a viable option? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You will probebly need some sort of api on the server side. In the client side you can then fetch the data drom the server side. You can use the fetch api of the brower or like TArvela mentioned using ajax or something like that to fetch the (json) data. Creating a api in express is fairly easy and you should be able to find out how you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build a sort of API server side and then use something like ajax/xhr requests to import data into the client.